# Migrating ssis package with ssdt without datatype changes

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, dts

I am doing a migration of SSIS packages from `SQL Server 2003` to `SQL Server 2016`.

The steps involved are as follows to migrate:

1. Open Sql server data tools (SSDT) 2016 or VS 2015.
2. Import Solution from 2016 Server
3. Add existing package from 2003 server to the solution to migrate
4. Deploy that package to 2016.

When I import the `.dtsx` package from 2003 server and use a database that is different to production, the `OLE DB Source` data type properties change type and length.

I would like to force these data type and length information to remain **same** and **not automatically change** when I change data sources.

Is there a to way force it to not change so that when deployed to sql server 2016, data type and length do not cause me issues.

I hope I have explained the scenario well. I am not `SSIS` developer so please advise on any information missed.

Comment: Just to double check, are you saying that the production server's datatypes don't match what is currently in the package, but you want them to continue to not match? That seems like an odd requirement if so; you'll likely to have failures in your packages. SSIS is very particular about ensuring the datatypes are correct and that they have the right length/scale/precision.

Comment: I’m importing the package from production 2003 server into ssdt 2016 in which case the data type and length is all ok happy days. However, when I change the data source to a test database, the data type and length to some columns in metadata get changed from say float to WSTR. I want it to not change and deploy to test server with test data source.

Comment: You could try changing the value of the `ValidateExternalMetadata` property to false.If, however you have a `varchar` on your production environment, and `nvarchar` in your test environment then  SSIS **is** going to have a *fit* if you leave the datatype as a `STR`. Generally your test and production environments should be set up the same. Perhaps you'd be better creating a branch project and testing on that, then you can change the data types in that one while leaving your main trunk as it was.

Comment: There's no SQL Server **2003** version - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016 and now 2017 - so which one are you talking about?

Comment: @Larnu - `ValidateExternalMetadata` resolves the issue with changing data type, however it creates the following error on a another workflow and changes data type from float to WSTR with below error `Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error  Validation error. Load data into ABC Staging Table: Load data into ABC Staging Table: Columns "abc_id" and "abc_return_id" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.  package (1).dtsx 0`

Comment: Which is exactly what I said it would do in my comment.

Comment: The types are same for the columns in both prod and test environment. Also validate external metadata was set to false on the data flow task that created the issue. But why does it create the above error on another workflow

Comment: Because now you've switch off the validation your trying to have a `nvarchar` stored into a `STR` (which is equivalent to a `varchar`). Like I said before SSIS has to have the right data types, and that's why it changed them automatically. Turning that off causes you're package to fail for exactly the thing your trying to do, and why I said it wasn't going to work.